# Add CSS rules at runtime in IE6 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Trying to get my site running in IE6 but having trouble with some runtime css stuff that I need to do.

I've tried both these:

```
$.rule('#post'+ i + '{ visibility:hidden;}').appendTo('style');
```

-

```
var postStyle = document.createElement('style');
postStyle.type = 'text/css';    
postStyle.innerHTML = '#post'+ i + '{ visibility:hidden;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head'[0].appendChild(postStyle);
```

Works in other browsers but not IE. I get this error:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you have to do this:

```
postStyle.styleSheet.cssText = whatever;
```

I've done this generally with a `try`/`catch` setup.

```
$('head').append($('<style/>', { id: "replaced-colors" }));

try {
  $('#replaced-colors').html(replaced);
}
catch (_ie) {
  $('#replaced-colors')[0].styleSheet.cssText = replaced;
}
```

as a real-life example.

Comment: You can avoid the `try/catch` by adding a rule to an existing stylesheet obtained from the `document.styleSheets` collection and checking for the existence of its `addRule()` method.